# Can you detect if Filter-branch has ever been run on a repository?

Tags: git

There's a lot of information about how to use `git filter-branch --force` to remove sensitive information from a repository. But is it possible to determine that this has been done after the fact? What evidence would you look for and how would you get it?

Comment: The short answer is no. A filtered repository is just a repository. The hash IDs won't match up with any versions that *weren't* filtered, but there is no obvious a priori determiner as to which is the "original" and which is the "modified" one. There *is* a period, right after filtering, when the repository has both old and new commits: since it's impossible to *change* any commit, filter-branch works by *copying* all the commits. But by the time you encounter the filtered repository, normally that's cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

Since git is distributed you may find another copy of the repo and then you can compare the repos to find differences. I think this is the only way, but I'm not a `filter-branch` expert.